# Ruby Hash initialization (default value nil)

Tags: ruby, hash

I've been reading the Ruby docs, and looking at some other posts on the issue, but I am still wondering about this:

```
#counts each number in an array once
array = [1,1,2,5,3,2,5,3,3,3]
numbers = {}
array.each { |num| numbers[num] += 1 }

=> in `block in mode': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

In the [Hash documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html) the default value for a `Hash` is `nil`, which is why I am getting this error I assume. Is there a better way to insert each key/(value += 1) into the numbers array?

Comment: Suppose you execute `numbers = Hash.new(0)` and then `numbers[num] += 1` when `num` is not a hash key.  Since you gave a default value of `0` when creating the hash, when Ruby finds that `num` is not a hash key, it creates a new hash element `h[num] = 0`. It then executes `h[num] += 1 # => 1` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: In case you are wondering, when `new` is given a default argument, Ruby won't create a hash element unless an assignment is performed.  If `h = Hash.new(0)`, for example, `h[6]` will equal `nil` in the if statement `if h[6] == 0`, resulting in the condition being `false`, and no hash element with key = 6 will be created (which otherwise would cause the if condition to be evaluted as `true`).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try passing a [default](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) value to your new hash as such

```
numbers = Hash.new(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly do it this way as well:

```
array.each { |num| numbers[num] = (numbers[num] || 0) + 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Variant with `inject` and `Hash.new(0)`

```
  numbers = [1,1,2,5,3,2,5,3,3,3].inject(Hash.new(0)){|numbers, number| numbers[number] +=1; numbers}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using the Hash default, you could also try something with `group_by`:

```
array = [1,1,2,5,3,2,5,3,3,3]
numbers = Hash[*array.group_by { |i| i }.flat_map { |k, v| [k , v.size] }]
```

There's probably a better way if you play around with it some.